# Multiple split of input?

Tags: python, input, python-3.x

I know that you can use split() to split a user input into two, but how would you split input that consists of multiple variables ? For example:
User input:

```
Shawn=14:soccer#2991842
```

What I would like to do:

```
name = Shawn
age = 14
course = soccer
idnumber = 2991842
```

What's the best way to do such thing ?

Comment: You you need to `parse` this text. You can do this by splitting the string when '=' exists, or ":" exists.. I'll write an example

Comment: What a strange format - an interesting assignment - though... Have you got any code you've tried already? Or any ideas on how to start going about this?

Comment: Jon Clements, I'm thinking I should use split but i'd like to get your assessment of what's the best way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried using Regex @kiasy

Answer (score 3):

```
str = 'Shawn=14:soccer#2991842'

keys = ['name', 'age', 'course', 'idnumber']
values = re.split('[=:#]', str)

print dict(zip(keys, values))
Out[114]: {'age': '14', 'course': 'soccer', 'idnumber': '2991842', 'name': 'Shawn'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Regex will work best here:

```
>>> from re import split
>>> mystr = "Shawn=14:soccer#2991842"
>>> split("\W", mystr)
['Shawn', '14', 'soccer', '2991842']
>>> lst = split("\W", mystr)
>>> name = lst[0]
>>> name
'Shawn'
>>> age = lst[1]
>>> age
'14'
>>> course = lst[2]
>>> course
'soccer'
>>> idnumber = lst[3]
>>> idnumber
'2991842'
>>>
```

Also, the above is a step-by-step demonstration.  You can actually just do:

```
name, age, course, idnumber = split("\W", mystr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just keep splitting the splits...

```
text2split = "Shawn=14:soccer#2991842"
name = text2split.split('=')[0]
age = text2split.split('=')[1].split(':')[0]
course = text2split.split('=')[1].split(':')[1].split('#')[0]
idnumber = text2split.split('=')[1].split(':')[1].split('#')[1]
```

This isn't the most elegant way to do it, but it'll work so long as `text2split` always has the same delimeters.

Comment: I would really appreciate if whomever down voted this would explain why.  Its a simple answer to a simple question.  It doesn't require anything beyond vanilla python, and with careful reading, is pretty easy to understand for anyone who knows how lists work in python.

Comment: They downvoted it because you didn't test it.  This code won't work because you are calling strings as functions.

Comment: Right, I forgot the ```.split``` in all of them. Stupid mistake.  Thanks for cluing me in!

Comment: I think it would make more sense to store the intermediate split results in variables, instead of doing the same `split`s over and over and over like this.

Comment: @abarnert, probably true, but I usually take the stance that its better to do more on one line and not use intermediate variables unless I have to

Comment: @wnnmaw: Why? Especially when it means making your source code more verbose and your program slower? Unless you live in some country where you get paid by the character but taxed on newlines, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @abarnet Well 99% of the scripts I have ever written, speed was never an issue.  I know I'll never be more than a mediocre programmer because I don't write my scripts with speed in mind.  Doing things in as few lines as possible makes more sense to me.  Plus, since my first language was FORTRAN, I get a special sense of satisfaction when I can combine a crazy number of steps into one (like list comprehensions). It just all seems more elegant if you can do it all in one go

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.

```
def splitStr(str):
   temp = str.split(':')

   temp_nameAge = temp[0].split('=')
   temp_courseId = temp[1].split('#')

   name = temp_nameAge[0]
   age = int(temp_nameAge[1])
   course = temp_courseId[0]
   idnumber = int(temp_courseId[1])

   print 'Name = %s, age = %i, course = %s, id_number = %i' % (name, age, course, idnumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is use split like: `string.split(":")`. 
Then you can change the format to "name:age:course:number"

Comment: There is probably a good reason why he wants the file to be in that format, you may consider editing this

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with storing them under dictionary keys, you could use [named group references](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

```
import re
x='shawn=14:soccer#2991842'
re.match(r'(?P<name>.*?)=(?P<age>.*):(?P<course>.*?)#(?P<idnumber>.*)', x).groupdict()
{'idnumber': '2991842', 'course': 'soccer', 'age': '14', 'name': 'shawn
```